# Can I install 11 speed cassette on 10 speed hub by skipping last cog?

Tags: road-bike, wheels, cassette

I have got Shimano Ultegra 6800 11 speed on carbon tubular wheels. For indoor trainer use I am going to buy regular wheels and use a special trainer tyre for it.

I found a cheap rear wheel for it, but it is compatible with 10 speed cassettes. Can I install my Ultegra 6800 cassette on it just by skipping one cog (largest or smallest)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shimano road 11 speed freehub bodies are not simply 1 sprocket wider than a 10 speed freehub body.

The 11 speed body is just 1.8mm wider than the 10 speed body, 11 speed sprocket spacing is less than 10 speed to fit the extra sprocket in (and I'm guessing there there may be a little more overhang of the freehub body flange).

You cannot remove the biggest sprocket as is it affixed to a spider. You *might* be able to get away with removing the smallest sprocket, if you can find a spacer of the right thickness to take up the extra space this leaves.

Comment: I've used multiple donut-shaped pieces of corrugated cardboard to create such spacers, they hold up pretty well, especially for an indoor trainer.